# How to retain the value of the listbox selected when user login to a form

Tags: java, listbox

I am working in an application where i have a list box with some values there ,i am selecting a  value from there and then i am submitting it.The value is inserted into the database properly.Now what i want ,i want when the user again login to the from he should be able to see that selected values in the listbox.I am able to pick the value from the database when the user is loggin into the system .But i can not  manage to show it selected ,Here is my code

```
<tr>

                <th>What would be the single biggest motivator in a potential new opportunity?</th>
                <td>
                    <select id="motivator" name="motivator" multiple="multiple">
                        <% while(rs8.next()){
                            motivatorString = rs8.getString("motivators");
                        %>                          
                        <option value ="<%=motivatorString %>" ><%=motivatorString %> </option>

                        <%} %>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

How can i achieve that ??

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selected="selected" for option like:

`<option value ="<%=motivatorString %>" selected="selected_only_if__motivatorString_value_equals_value_from_db"><%=motivatorString %> </option>`

selected_only_if__motivatorString_value_equals_value_from_db is just a placeholder to tell u that replace it with "selected" when the string matches the value in DB

Comment: selected_only_if__motivatorString_value_equals_value_from_db  should i place if condition there ??

Comment: Yes. that is just a hint to you. Based on your code/values, you can do something like

${motivatorString ==  value_from_db
             ? 'selected="selected"' 
             : ''
             }

Comment: I have <%=motivator%>  string which is holding the value from the database .How to write the sysntax